# new Object created without defined prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm working on a Cartesian coordinate library, and I try to simple create a class, define prototype and create instances.

But in this simple case, my cartesian object don't have any method on it.

```
let Cartesian = function(instance, opts) {
  let pos = opts.pos || {x:0, y: 0}
  /* .. Logic here .. */
  return {pos: pos}
}

console.log("Before : ", Cartesian.prototype.getPosition)

Cartesian.prototype.getPosition = function() {
  return true
}

console.log("After : ", Cartesian.prototype.getPosition)

CartesianExport = {
  create: function (instance, opts) {
    console.log("Create new : ", Cartesian.prototype.getPosition)
    let c = new Cartesian(instance, opts)
    console.log("Created : ", c, c.getPosition)
    return c
  }
}

module.exports = CartesianExport
```

And this is my console

```
Before : undefined
After : function () { return true }
Create new : function () { return true }
Created :  Object {pos: Object} undefined
```

I don't understand why I got `cartesian.getPosition is not a function` when I try to use it.

Comment: In `Cartesian` - `return {pos: pos}` - why are you doing that? I think you've misunderstood how Javascript constructors work.

Comment: In my case I return other attribute, I can access from `c.pos`

Comment: in that case, the returned object is not a `Cartesian`

Comment: That `return` statement is throwing away the object the constructor was constructing.

Comment: hooo... now I understand my mistake. the `Cartesian` object is `this` on the constructor, so I have to return this

Comment: @Arthur You *can* `return this`, but generally you would return nothing and allow `this` to automatically be used. The rule is that a constructor will always return the `this` object you create unless you return a different object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
function Cartestian(opts) {
  this.pos = opts.pos || {x: 0, y: 0};
}
```

When you say `return {pos: pos};` in your constructor, the prototypeless object `{pos: pos}` is returned instead of a new instance of `Cartesian`. The instance is overridden with the returned value. So `new Cartesian(...)` evaluates to a object without a prototype. This is what I mean:

```
function IncorrectlyDefined(obj) {
  return obj;
}

var someObj = {x: 0, y: 0};
var x = new IncorrrectlyDefined(someObj);
// x === someObj
```

Comment: To be more clear with the solution. To get the Class prototypes on the `new Object` you have to return `this` on the `constructor`

Answer (score -3):

there is No Declaration of cartesian.getPosition function that's only your Getting Undefined. So U can Declare The Function c.getPosition Function You can able to get that.data